# Chain complex of a $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^1$ with $n$ $1$-simplices

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Describe the chain complex of a $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^1$ with $n$ $1$-simplices.

I cannot understand this question. How can we come up with a $\Delta$-complex structure on the circle with an arbitrary number $n$ of $1$-simplices? Perhaps $S^1$ is a typo and should be $S^n$? But even then I do not know how $S^n$ can be constructed from $n$ $1$-simplices. I would greatly appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: For $0\leq k < n$ consider the path $\gamma_k\colon [0,1] \to S^1\subset \mathbb{C}$ where $\gamma_k(t) = exp(2\pi i * \frac{k + t}{n})$. This traces an arc between $exp(2\pi i * \frac{k}{n})$ and $exp(2\pi i * \frac{k + 1}{n})$. Use these to help construct your $\Delta$-complex structure.

Comment: If you don't need to be this explicit, you can just choose a homeomorphism between $S^1$ and the boundary of an $n$-gon.

Comment: To be a $\Delta-$complex structure, I need each map $\sigma_\alpha : \Delta^n \to X$ to be such that $A \subset X$ is open iff $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(A)$ is open in $\Delta^n$ for each $\sigma_\alpha$. From the construction you gave, don't we have half-closed arcs or closed arcs open as well?

Comment: @William Oh I see this isn't a problem since every path intersects another at a point. So if we consider a closed or half-closed arc with an endpoint then the inverse image of this arc in a neighboring path will be a single point, which is not open in $[0,1]$. Hence the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $n>0$. Let $0\leq k < n$ and consider the path

$$\begin{array}\\
\gamma_k\colon &[0,1]&\to &S^1\subset\mathbb{C} \\
&t &\mapsto &e^{2\pi i  \frac{k+t}{n}}
\end{array}$$

Then $\gamma_k$ is an embedded path from $\xi ^k \to \xi^{k+1}$ where $\xi = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ is the standard primitive $n$-th root of unity.

For the $0$-simplices of our $\Delta$-complex structure, take the maps $\sigma_{0,k}\colon \Delta^0 \to S^1$ where $\sigma_{0,k}(1) = \xi ^k$ for $0\leq k<n$. Fix a homeomorphism $\varphi\colon\Delta^1 \to [0,1]$ and define the $1$-simplices of our $\Delta$-complex structure as

$$ \sigma_{1,k} = \gamma_k\circ \varphi \colon \Delta^1 \to S^1 $$
I'll leave it to you to verify the requirements of a $\Delta$-complex structure.

Then the chain complex simply looks like $\dots \rightarrow 0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}^n$. To finish describing the chain complex it remains for you to determine $\partial \sigma_{1,k}$ for each $k$.